# How to initialize policy for Mountain-Car problem?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to solve the discrete [Mountain-Car problem from OpenAI gym](https://gym.openai.com/envs/MountainCar-v0/) using a simple policy gradient method.

For now, my agent never actually starts making progress. In OpenAI's implementation, the agent gets a reward of -1 for every timestep, and the episodes ends when the agent reaches the top of the mountain, or when the 200 timesteps limit is reached. To only commence learning a useful policy, the agent needs to stumble on the top of the mountain at least a first time by chance. However, it seems to me that the odds of stumbling there by chance are really tiny (I ran a random agent for more than 5000 episodes and it never stumbled once on top).

**How do people usually initialize their policy on that problem?**

I don't want to cheat by giving my agent a heuristic about how to solve the problem but at the same time it feels like it could take a very long time before it only can start to learn.

Comment: I think initialization alone is not working. You probably need to train your network e.g. with the value function as auxiliary task and maybe entropy regularization. This way you encourage the policy to encode some structure and force it to always perform some exploration besides sampling from the softmax.

Comment: Also note that the gym implementation is not fulfilling the Markov property as an episode ends after 200 timesteps.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to solve Mountain Car using REINFORCE for some time now. Now, I am trying Reward Engineering. You can add the absolute value of the velocity into the reward, so that it gets an incentive to acquire maximum kinetic energy, and hence get out of the hill.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be solved in the usual way. Every time it gives -1 as a reward whether you are progressing or not. On the reward end, I did a small change that is if the position (observation[0]) of the car is greater than -0.2, I took the reward as 1. I took as 1 because -0.2 position is top of the hill which means our random actions giving somewhat fruitful results. This approach solved my problem.

I solved this problem kind of traditional deep learning model implementation if you need more details then check [my article](https://medium.com/@ashoktankala/solving-curious-case-of-mountaincar-reward-problem-using-openai-gym-keras-tensorflow-in-python-d031c471b346) once.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Ashok. We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality 
machine learning information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of 
links, due to linkrot. Can you post a full citation & a brief summary of the 
article, in case it goes dead?

Comment: @gung : Added brief summary according to my knowledge

Comment: Thanks, @Ashok. Can you include a full citation for your article?